# How to obtain a count of objects per auth.user?

Tags: django, django-models, django-aggregation

I have a Project model similar to:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ...
    lead_analyst=models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='lead_analyst')
    ...
```

I want to use django aggregation to return all users with a count of projects per user. Something like:

```
models.User.objects.annotate(project_count=Count('project_set'))
```

Only that doesn't work because the `auth.user` has no knowledge about my Project class. I get the error:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'project_set' into field. Choices are: date_joined, email, employee, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, lead_analyst, logentry, message, password, siteprofile, submitter, user_permissions, username

Two part question, really:

1. How to obtain this count of Projects per `auth.user`
2. Is there a better way to write the association between my Project class and the `auth.user` class that would make this aggregation viable?

Or should I just break into raw sql for aggregations (either via raw sql in django or a view in the database)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your models - that's exactly how to set up that relation. The problem is simply that you've specified a `related_name` in the foreignkey, so as far as User is concerned, there's no `project_set` - there's a `lead_analyst` instead. In fact you can see this in the list of fields given by your error message.

So your aggregate query should read:

```
models.User.objects.annotate(project_count=Count('lead_analyst'))
```

(I must say, I think you've chosen a misleading related name here - you would be better off sticking to the default, in which case your original syntax would have worked.)

Comment: Well, I'm a frickin idiot... :-)

Reason for related_name is that I have more than one field relating to User in that model. I just didn't display all of them in my snippet above.

Thanks for your help.